# How to unit test a UIButton that calls an asynchronous task

Tags: swift, unit-testing, asynchronous, xctest, ibaction

I am trying to test a login method triggered by a IBAction that if the login failed (if the completion hander returned a error), I want to present an alert controller, but the login method is obviously an asynchronous.

The `loginUser` method is already mocked and always returns `handler(nil, .EmptyData)` on the main thread like so:

```
func loginUser(from url: URL, with username: String, and password: String, completionHandler: @escaping (DrivetimeUserProfile?, DrivetimeAPIError.LoginError?) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(nil, .EmptyData)
        }
    }
```

Here is the IBAction

```
@IBAction func onLoginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let url = URL(string: USER_LOGIN_ENDPOINT) else { return }

        let username = userNameTextField.text
        let password = passwordTextField.text

        client.loginUser(from: url, with: username!, and: password!) { (data, error) in

            if let error = error {

                switch error {

                case .EmptyData:
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        presentAlertVC()
                    }

                case .CannotDecodeJson:
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         presentAlertVC()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My question is, how do I test to see if the handler returns a `.EmptyData` error, the alert controller will show?

Here is my attempt on the test, the set is the viewController in test:

```
func testLoginButtin_ShouldPresentAlertContollerIfErrorIsNotNil() {

    sut.onLoginButtonTapped(sut.loginButton)

    let alert = sut.presentingViewController

    XCTAssertNotNil(alert)


}
```

Comment: To be honest, when I look at the code, are you sure this is something you want to test? The correctness is obvious from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tl;dr Answer originally sought comes at end*

Based on your description, I don't think you need to use `DispatchQueue.main` in this section of production code. Since Client's `loginUser(from:with:and:completionHandler:)` does something asynchronous and then calls the completion handler, it can guarantee that the completion handler is called on the main thread. And this would happen after the response has been decoded in the background.

If that's true, then in the view controller's `onLoginButtonTapped(_)`, there's no need for the completion handler to *again* dispatch to the main queue. We already know that it's running on the main queue, so it can just call `self.presentAlertVC()` without any tricks.

This brings us to the test code. Your faked `loginUser` doesn't have to schedule anything on `DispatchQueue.main`. The real version does, but the fake doesn't have to. We can eliminate that, making the test code even simpler. All the test code can by synchronous, eliminating the need to use XCTestExpectation.

Now your fake client shouldn't call the completion handler with hard-coded values. We want each test to be able to configure what it wants. This will let you test every path. If you're not already doing the substitution of the fake using a protocol, let's introduce one:

```
protocol ClientProtocol {
    func loginUser(from url: URL,
                   with username: String,
                   and password: String,
                   completionHandler: @escaping (DrivetimeUserProfile?, DrivetimeAPIError.LoginError?) -> Void)
}
```

You may already be doing this. If not, then you're creating a test-specific subclass of your client right now. Go with the protocol. So in your view controller, you'll have a number of outlets and this client:

```
@IBOutlet private(set) var loginButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet private(set) var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet private(set) var passwordTextField: UITextField!
var client: ClientProtocol = Client()
```

Make the outlets `private(set)` instead of `private` so that tests can access them.

Here are the tests I'd write. Bear with me, I'll eventually get to the one you asked about. First, let's test that the outlets are set up. For my example, I'm going to assume you're using a storyboard-based view controller.

```
final class ViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {
    private var sut: ViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        sut = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }
    
    func test_outlets_shouldBeConnected() {
        sut.loadViewIfNeeded()

        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.loginButton, "loginButton")
        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.usernameTextField, "usernameTextField")
        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.passwordTextField, "passwordTextField")
    }
}
```

Next, I want to test something you haven't mentioned: that when the user taps the login button, it calls `loginUser` passing the expected parameters. For this, we can pass a mock object that lets us verify how `loginUser` is called. It's going to capture the call count and all parameters. It has a verify method to confirm most of the parameters. A separate method gives tests a way to call the completion handler.

```
private class MockClient: ClientProtocol {
    private var loginUserCallCount = 0
    private var loginUserArgsURL: [URL] = []
    private var loginUserArgsUsername: [String] = []
    private var loginUserArgsPassword: [String] = []
    private var loginUserArgsCompletionHandler: [(DrivetimeUserProfile?, DrivetimeAPIError.LoginError?) -> Void] = []

    func loginUser(from url: URL,
                   with username: String,
                   and password: String,
                   completionHandler: @escaping (DrivetimeUserProfile?, DrivetimeAPIError.LoginError?) -> Void) {
        loginUserCallCount += 1
        loginUserArgsURL.append(url)
        loginUserArgsUsername.append(username)
        loginUserArgsPassword.append(password)
        loginUserArgsCompletionHandler.append(completionHandler)
    }

    func verifyLoginUser(from url: URL,
                         with username: String,
                         and password: String,
                         file: StaticString = #file,
                         line: UInt = #line) {
        XCTAssertEqual(loginUserCallCount, 1, "call count", file: file, line: line)
        XCTAssertEqual(url, loginUserArgsURL.first, "url", file: file, line: line)
        XCTAssertEqual(username, loginUserArgsUsername.first, "username", file: file, line: line)
        XCTAssertEqual(password, loginUserArgsPassword.first, "password", file: file, line: line)
    }
    
    func invokeLoginUserCompletionHandler(profile: DrivetimeUserProfile?,
                                          error: DrivetimeAPIError.LoginError?,
                                          file: StaticString = #file,
                                          line: UInt = #line) {
        guard let handler = loginUserArgsCompletionHandler.first else {
            XCTFail("No loginUser completion handler captured", file: file, line: line)
            return
        }
        handler(profile, error)
    }
}
```

Since we want to use this for several tests, let's put it in the test fixture:

```
private var sut: ViewController!
private var mockClient: MockClient! // 

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
    mockClient = MockClient() // 
    sut.client = mockClient // 
}

override func tearDown() {
    sut = nil
    mockClient = nil // 
    super.tearDown()
}
```

Now I'm ready to write that first test that tapping the login button calls the client:

```
func test_tappingLoginButton_shouldLoginUserWithEnteredUsernameAndPassword() {
    sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
    sut.usernameTextField.text = "USER"
    sut.passwordTextField.text = "PASS"

    sut.loginButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    
    mockClient.verifyLoginUser(from: URL(string: "https://your.url")!, with: "USER", and: "PASS")
}
```

Notice that the test isn't calling `sut.onLoginButtonTapped(sut.loginButton)`. Instead, the test is telling the login button to handle a `.touchUpInside`. The name of the action method is irrelevant, so the IBAction can be declared `private`.

Finally, we come to your original question. Given some result passed to the completion handler, is an alert presented? For this, we can use my library [MockUIAlertController](https://github.com/jonreid/MockUIAlertController). Add it to your test target. It's written in Objective-C, so create a bridging header that imports `MockUIAlertController.h`.

The alert verifier captures information about the presented alert, without actually presenting any alerts. The safest way to ensure that no actual alerts are triggered by unit tests is to add it to the test fixture:

```
private var sut: ViewController!
private var mockClient: MockClient!
private var alertVerifier: QCOMockAlertVerifier! // 

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
    mockClient = MockClient()
    sut.client = mockClient
    alertVerifier = QCOMockAlertVerifier() // 
}

override func tearDown() {
    sut = nil
    mockClient = nil
    alertVerifier = nil // 
    super.tearDown()
}
```

With alerts safely captured, we can now write the test you wanted in the first place:

```
func test_invokeLoginCompletionHandler_withEmptyData_shouldPresentAlert() {
    sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
    sut.loginButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    
    mockClient.invokeLoginUserCompletionHandler(profile: nil, error: .EmptyData)

    XCTAssertEqual(alertVerifier.presentedCount, 1, "presented count")
    // more assertions here...
}
```

Because we built up enough infrastructure, the test code is simple. The [QCOMockAlertVerifier has many other properties](https://github.com/jonreid/MockUIAlertController/blob/master/Source/MockUIAlertController/QCOMockAlertVerifier.h) you can test. You can also have it execute button actions.

With this test in place, it's easy to write others. You can invoke the completion handler with the other error case, or with a valid profile. No async testing is needed.

If you really, really need to explicitly schedule the alert on the main thread instead of calling it directly, we can do that. Create an expectation, and ask the alert verifier to fulfill it. Add a short wait before asserting.

```
func test_invokeLoginCompletionHandler_withEmptyData_shouldPresentAlert() {
    sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
    sut.loginButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "alert presented") // 
    alertVerifier.completion = { expectation.fulfill() } // 
    
    mockClient.invokeLoginUserCompletionHandler(profile: nil, error: .EmptyData)

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 0.001) // 
    XCTAssertEqual(alertVerifier.presentedCount, 1, "presented count")
    // more assertions here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth tutorial on this testing, behind login method `loginUser(from:with:and:completionHandler:)` is basically a `datatask` object, and so if there is `data` return, I then parse it using `JSONDecoder().decode` to get my `userProfile` and use the completion handler to pass it to the closure, which is still in the background thread, are you suggesting that the passing back to the closure should be done on a main thread?

Comment: Yes, it would simplify a great deal. I have seen situations where it doesn't make sense to do so, but they are rare.

Comment: Thank you, by the way, looking forward to your book, when are you aiming to finish?

Comment: Some time this year. I'll update the book page with periodic updates.

Answer (score 1):

For any kind of **async call unit test** you should use `expectation` like this:

```
// Create an expectation for a async task.
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "async task")

// Perform async call
myAsyncCall() { (data, x, y) in

    // In completion callback, make sure you achieve your needs.
    // For example check data is not nil
    XCTAssertNotNil(data, "No data was downloaded.")

    // Fulfill the expectation to indicate that the task has finished successfully.
    expectation.fulfill()
}

// Wait until the expectation is fulfilled, with a timeout of 10 seconds or any you need.
wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10.0)
```

About your case, you should extract the **async call** from the **IBAction** and write two different tests. one for **action** and one for **presenting alert**.
I recommend you to add extra tests for the **async call it self** too. (Success, Fail, etc.)

Comment: But wouldn't the problem still exists? so if I create a `performLogin` method and call the client `loginUser` in that method, it would still be a function calling an async task and I can't do expectations

Comment: You should test `performLogin` separately and use a mock instead of real api call for `loginUser` for each success or failure state you may have. Check out this WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/417/

Comment: thanks, I finished watching the video but I'm still struggle as to what I really need to test, or should the real question be do I really need a unit test for this since all the api calls are fully tested

Comment: You should mock it in any way you need to reproduce any cases. Not testing it with real (fully tested) API